# Ruby gem dependencies on offline server

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, offline

I have a server that is totally disconnected from the Internet (for some strange security reasons).

How can I make the Ruby dependencies to various gems work in that environment? It might work with **Bundler**, but how do I install Bundler using **gem** without a Internet connection?

Comment: You can install bundler from a `.gem` file. Go to [rubygems](http://rubygems.org/gems/bundler/), hit 'Download' button, and then do `gem install bundler-1.1.4.gem`. Then you can use [`bundler package`](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-package.1.html) to pack all necessary gems into `vendor/cache` directory of your app, so you can deploy them to your server along with the app.

Comment: Thank you!I will try it right away. Will Ruby find all the gems in vendor/cache automatically or do I need to specify a certain load path?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-package.1.html) if you do `bundle install --local` in your app's directory on the server bundler will look for gems only in `vendor/cache`.

Comment: yes, thanks. But I meant when running it.

  *ruby someprogram.rb*

  in `require': cannot load such file -- trollop (LoadError)

Comment: Added this as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293339/how-to-execute-ruby-program-with-locally-installed-gems

Comment: @KL-7 Please create an answer so we can mark it as done =)

Comment: It gives a warning when running `bundler package` to use `bundle package` instead, which worked for me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can download bundler as a `.gem` file from rubygems and install it on the server with

```
gem install /path/to/bundler.gem
```

Then you can pack all gems required for your application into `./vendor/cache` directory with

```
bundle package
```

If now you deploy your app (along with `./vendor/cache` directory) to the server and run

```
bundle install --local
```

bundler won't go to rubygems, but instead will install all gems from `./vendor/cache` directory.

See `bundler-package` [docs](http://bundler.io/v1.13/man/bundle-package.1.html) for more information.

Comment: gem fetch bundler for the first step