# How to execute Ruby program with locally installed gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have installed my dependencies using

```
bundle package
```

Then transferred them to the offline server and running:

```
> bundle install --local
Using mime-types (1.19)
Using rest-client (1.6.7)
Using trollop (1.16.2)
Using bundler (1.1.4)
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
```

However, it is not possible to run the application:

```
ruby someprogram.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- trollop (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from someprogram.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

What do I need to specify to Ruby to be able to run locally installed gems?

Comment: > gem environment
    RubyGems Environment:
      - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
      - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-linux]
      - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
      - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
      - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
      - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
        - ruby
        - x86_64-linux
      - GEM PATHS:
         - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
         - /root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1

Comment: > gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.1.0)
bundler (1.1.4)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.4)
minitest (2.5.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.4)

Comment: I guess you're missing [`bundle exec`](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html) in front of your `ruby someprogram.rb` command.

Comment: Please enter a proper answer so I can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing [`bundle exec`](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-exec.1.html) in front of your `ruby someprogram.rb` command.

Comment: You can also use the --binstubs switch to point to a directory in your path if you don't want to use bundle exec. - see http://tomafro.net/2012/06/tip-bundler-with-binstubs for the instructions