# Ruby Bundle Install in deployment mode

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm installing a ruby git-repo on several servers which have **no internet** connectivity. I had cloned that repo to my local machine, and used `$ bundle install --path vendor/bundle` to package all dependencies. Then I copied the whole directory to the target server, and tried `$ bundle install --deployment`, which still attempting resources from rubygems.org, hence not solving any dependencies as expected:

> Fetching source index for https://ruby.taobao.org/
>   Could not find ffi-1.9.3 in any of the sources

According to [bundler.io](http://bundler.io/bundle_install.html):

> The --deployment flag activates a number of deployment-friendly conventions:
>   Isolate all gems into **vendor/bundle**

which does not work in my case. Any thing am I doing wrong?

Comment: This should be helpful.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291235/ruby-gem-dependencies-on-offline-server

Comment: @aadarshs any differences between `bundle install --path ...` and `bundle package`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bundle install` will grab the gems from rubygems when run.

`bundle package` grabs the gems and packages them in vendor/cache.

The `package` command will copy the `.gem` files for your gems in the bundle into `./vendor/cache`. Afterward, when you run `bundle install`, Bundler will use the gems in the cache in preference to the ones on rubygems.org.

http://bundler.io/bundle_package.html