# Jekyll gem install error: unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for History.md

Tags: ruby, docker, jekyll, dockerfile

I've created a Dockerfile to install jekyll-2.5.3.gem.

**Docker Code:**

```
FROM base-ubuntu

COPY jekyll-2.5.3.gem  /tmp/jekyll-2.5.3.gem

RUN apt-get update && \

    apt-get install -y ruby-dev build-essential nodejs python && \

    gem install /tmp/jekyll-2.5.3.gem

EXPOSE 4000

WORKDIR /var/jekyll

ENTRYPOINT ["jekyll"]
```

I need to build a docker image with a container consisting of jekyll installation.

**Docker build command :-**

```
docker build -t myimage /c/Users/src/jekyll
```

The above docker build command hangs in jekyll installation and displays the following conversion errors.

**LOG:**

```
unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for History.md, skipping

unable to convert U+2022 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/kramdown/converter/pdf.rb, skipping

unable to convert U+2014 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/pygments/popen.rb, skipping

unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for COPYING, skipping

unable to convert "\xC2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/parslet/atoms/base.rb, skipping

unable to convert U+2014 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/addressable/uri.rb, skipping

unable to convert "\xC2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for README.md, skipping
```

Is there a work around for this issue ? As part of my project I need to stick to the Jekyll version 2.5.3.

Thanks,
Soumya.

Comment: Could you also post a Dockerfile for 'base-ubuntu' image?
Also, which OS do you use?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 vagrant machine and ssh client to run the docker images.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for that is using [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) instead. It's "just the right tool for the job" that ensures that application runs with proper versions of all the libraries you care about. First, install it:

```
gem install bundler
```

Then create a `Gemfile` at the root of your project with contents like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'jekyll', '2.5.3'
```

...then in the same folder do:

```
bundle install
```

...so dependencies you specified in your Gemfile are resolved and installed. Now, to run your application with dependencies bundled, run whatever command you were formerly running prepended with `bundle exec`, like so:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

An offline setup is not too different, it revolves around `bundle package` (so all the needed gems are packaged with the application; checking them into version control is a bad idea!) and `bundle install --local` (so it doesn't use external sources), see [this answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11301073/2076787).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The purpose of my docker file is to install the jekyll-2.5.3.gem which is already present in the current directory. I'm purposefully avoiding web access. At the moment, I want to run this simple docker file (it is not connected to the project) to create docker container with jekyll installation. Is this possible? How can I avoid the formatting issue ? I want to make changes within the docker file. This docker container is standalone and is not associated with the project.

Comment: @SoumyaSundarrajan that's a significant detail that should be in the question **in bold**. You're also using `apt-get` there, apparently it's OK. Assuming you get that sorted out, `jekyll` isn't autonomous and has [a few immediate dependencies](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/jekyll.gemspec) you have to install too. And dependencies of these dependencies as well.

Comment: @D-side..Thanks for your response. I had checked the link and installed the eight dependencies for Jekyll gem. This has reduced the number of errors. But I'm still getting four formatting errors.
Errors:
unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for COPYING, skipping

Comment: @SoumyaSundarrajan those are most likely warnings about documentation, not errors. Try installing with `--no-ri`  and `--no-rdoc`.

Comment: Formatting issue has been resolved after adding nokogiri-1.6.7-java.gem and rdoc-4.2.0.gem in the docker file. Thanks for your help. Cheers.

Comment: @SoumyaSundarrajan well, Bundler exists exactly so you don't have to do all this by hand. Manual dependency resolution is hard.