# Ruby Bundler - handling gems in multiple VMs

Tags: ruby, bundler

Gems and gem dependencies are becoming a bit of a nightmare for our organisation. I am the only developer at the moment using Ruby but with more coming onboard all the time we really need to get Gems and dependencies in order.

The problem is that development VMs do not have internet access but do have access to a shared directory that we can map to. Currently I have just been downloading gems and dependencies one at a time to my local net connected laptop and then moving gems to the shared directory and then copying them over to the VM - clearly this is nonsense and I need to start using bundler or some other system.

I am sure other companies have had similar problems what is considered best practise?

Comment: Surely Ruby developers had that in mind. You can try [hosting gems on your own server](http://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/).

Answer (score 1):

Loading gems from project(not system or internet) can be solution of that problem. So, it means download all needed gems and then copy vendor folder(can use any memory from flash or CD) to each project and them will be can load needed gems from this folder.

[Ruby gem dependencies on offline server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291235/ruby-gem-dependencies-on-offline-server)